# Launch Dataproc PySpark job from Cloud Source

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-source-repos

I am currently launching PySpark using `DataProcPySparkOperator` from Airflow with a script in Cloud Storage

```
run_pyspark_job = dataproc_operator.DataProcPySparkOperator(
    task_id='run-dataproc-pyspark',
    main='gs://my-repo/my-script.py',
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,
    region='europe-west4'
)
```

Is there anyway to pass a script from Cloud Source Repositories ? For a given repository one can get the absolute link to the script but it does not seems to be accepted by the DAG.

```
https://source.cloud.google.com/my-organisation/my-repo/+/master:my-script.py
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

All Python and Jar files referenced must be from a HDFS or HDFS-compatible file system, or located in a Google Cloud Storage **bucket**. For more information, you can refer to the [Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataProcPySparkOperator).

To create a Cloud Storage bucket, you can use following `Make Bucket` [command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mb):

```
gsutil mb -l us-central1 gs://$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID-data
```

You can do this as follows:

If you want to use your files from Cloud Source Repositories, firstly you need to clone repository and then, copy the contents of the data to Google Cloud Storage

```
gsutil cp -r dir1/dir2 gs://$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID-data
```

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.